# Probability of me fetching all distinct pokemon Tazons from chips packet.

Tags: probability, combinations

In order to collect all pokemon Tazos, I went to a shop and bought bags of chips. Now I am  worried whether I have bought enough bags of chips or not. You need to tell me the probability of getting all the  distinct Pokemon Tazos from the N bags of chips. 
Lets say N is the number of bags i bought and K is the distinct pokemon available.
So how do i calculate probability?

Comment: Coupon collectors problem.

Answer (score 0):

The probability of choosing only 1 distinct number from 0 to k in n

tries is

(1/k)$^{n−1}$ . Hope You can take it further from here on.

Answer (score 0):

You want to count how many functions $\{1, \ldots, n\} \to \{1, \ldots, k\}$ are surjections, the answer is $S(n, k) k!$. In order to find the probability, divide this by the number of all functions from the set of bags to the set of Pokemons:

$$p_{n, k} = \frac{S(n, k) \cdot k!}{k^n}.$$

For example setting $n = 5$ and $k = 2$ gives

$$\frac{15 \cdot 2!}{2^5} = \frac{15}{16}.$$

Here $S$ denotes the Stirling number of second kind.